# Calculate the sum of workdays until today using SQL

Tags: sql, sum

I have the Base Table and I am trying to get the Result Table.

I am using this code to get the two first columns of the Result Table.

The Overdue column should give the SUM of the WorkingDays until today's date.

How can I get all 3 columns in the same select statement?

```
;With cte as (
Select [Id] ,[Event_Id] ,[StartDate] ,[EndDate] ,[WorkingDay] From BaseTable
)

Select 
    Id, 
    SUM(WorkingDays) as Planned
From cte
Group By Id, Event_Id
```

[image]

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: what is the logic of planned and overdue

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Planned referes to the SUM of WorkingDays and Overdue refers to the SUM of passed WorkingDays.

Comment: @ElioFernandes Maybe you can use a subquery for calculating overdue